Camera video doesn't load - multi unilbs network error
I'm using the Agora RTC SDK (agora-rtc-sdk-ng) for web video chat sessions on a Laravel/Vue based site and am getting a problem with the video camera feed.
The following warning/error exception is logged by the Agora component:-
11:25:10:288 Agora-SDK [WARNING]: [client-5a465] multi unilbs network error, retry AgoraRTCException: AgoraRTCError NETWORK_ERROR: Network Error
    ue https://example.com/build/assets/app-aab0baaa.js:1604
    Si https://example.com/build/assets/app-aab0baaa.js:1626
    zn https://example.com/build/assets/app-aab0baaa.js:1626

<full stack trace redacted as question filtered>

I have run the same code on my Mac development laptop with no issues however when the code is built on the server (Debian) it fails with the above problem.
